# How can send request server and receive response by php

Tags: php, codeigniter, httprequest

Request format:
http://site.com/VSServices/SendSms.ashx?login=CLIENT_LOGIN&pass=CLIENT_PASSWORD&from=Paulx&to=442081368002&&text=Hello

response is xml

Comment: i dont know what you really mean here...but I guess you are looking for CURL....

Comment: Use CURL. This may be what you want.

Comment: Request is `this` and Response is `that` but Question is `Unknown`

Comment: Question is very abstract with ample of ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

As per your post,what i understand is you want a code for the curl example in php. The below code will make a HTTP request with curl and return the response in $content.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.anydomain.com/anyapi.php?a=parameters');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
?>
```

hope this will help else give me more information for your question so i can help you.